# Why Singleton in python calls __init__ multiple times and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, initialization, singleton

i've this implementation of singleton pattern in python, but i've noticed
that the **init** is called, uselessly, everytime i call MyClass, despite the same instance is returned.

How can i avoid it?

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        object.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class Singleton(object):
  _instance = None

  def __new__(cls):
    if not isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
        cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance

class MyClass(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print("should be printed only 1 time")
        self.x=Test()
        pass

a = MyClass() # prints: "should be printed only 1 time"
b = MyClass() # prints ( again ): "should be printed only 1 time"

print(a,b) # prints: 0x7ffca6ccbcf8 0x7ffca6ccbcf8
print(a.x,b.x) # prints: 0x7ffca6ccba90 0x7ffca6ccba90
```

Comment: Because `__init__` is *always* called, if implemented, on whatever `__new__` returns - why don't you do the initialisation in `__new__` when `cls._instance is None`?

Comment: cls._instance is never None if you must call super().__new__ to create the instance as first thing in __new__ of child class. I need the created instance to set an instance variable

Comment: @jonrsharpe: An instance's `__init__` is _not_ always called, it depends on the type of what `__new__` returns. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__): "If `__new__()` does not return an instance of _cls_, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked."

Comment: @martineau good to know, thanks - in general, though, wouldn't `__new__` be returning a `cls` instance?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sure, but "in general" isn't the same thing as an emphasized "always". In fact, I've seen designs that utilize this fact, although I don't see how it helps with this particular question.

Comment: @martineau fair point, I'll bear that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `__new__` doesn't return an object, it returns an unitialized object on which `__init__` is called afterwards.

You can't avoid that at all. What you can do is the following(using metatypes):

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, mmbs):
        super(Singleton, self).__init__(name, bases, mmbs)
        self._instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._instance

class Test(metaclass = Singleton):
    # __metaclass__ = Singleton # in python 2.7
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        print("Only ever called once")
```

Comment: So where should i've to put the constructor for your Test class? inside __new__ ?

Comment: @Joseph if you do it this way you can implement `__init__` in `Test` and it will only be called once.

Comment: @Joseph, with this, you can code `Test` without worrying that the constructor is called twice :) Updated the answer

Comment: there are so many singleton implementations for Python, this was the only one that worked without editing. Super thanks!

Comment: in what case it still calling the __init__ more then once , this is not working for me 
python 3.7

Comment: Same problem here in python 3.9. I still get multiple instances; __init__ is called multiple times

Comment: @BrianReinhold @user63898 This still works for me in 3.10. Keep in mind that if you have subclasses of `Test`, those will all be initialized too and call a respective init. But subclassing a singleton class was definitely not intended in the answer.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I am not intentionally subclassing my 'singleton' but you are probably right about the tests doing their own creation of this class during the import and the source code being tested is doing its own. I made special test methods in my source code that the tests would call to get my singleton object and then the results made sense.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple, but totally viable way to implement what you want, which doesn't require super or meta classes, is to just make your class a Python module, which are essentially Singleton objects.

Here's what I mean:

`myclass.py`:

```
class Test(object):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("in MyClass.__init__, should be printed only 1 time")
        self.x = Test()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        classname = type(self).__name__
        return globals()[classname]

MyClass = MyClass()
```

`client.py`:

```
from myclass import MyClass

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()

print(a, b)
print(a.x, b.x)
```

Output:

```
in MyClass.__init__, should be printed only 1 time
<myclass.MyClass object at 0x02200B30> <myclass.MyClass object at 0x02200B30>
<myclass.Test object at 0x02200C10> <myclass.Test object at 0x02200C10>
```

It's possible to derive a subclass from MyClass, but you'd have to do it something like this:

```
class Derived(type(MyClass)):
    def __init__(self):
        print("in Derived.__init__, should be printed only 1 time")

Derived = Derived()
```

Afterwards you could add this to 'client.py':

```
from myclass import Derived

a = Derived()
b = Derived()

print(a,b)
print(a.x,b.x)  # AttributeError: 'Derived' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Wow. Think outside the box. But you can't inherit from the class anymore

Comment: @WorldSEnder: I believe you're mistaken—it's quite possible to derive a subclass from the class as shown and the end of my (updated) answer.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__`, if implemented, is *always* called on whatever gets returned by `__new__`; in general, you should be implementing one or the other, not both. You could implement `__new__` on `MyClass`, instead, and initialise the `x` attribute only if it doesn't already exist:

```
class MyClass(Singleton):

    def __new__(cls):
        inst = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)
        if not hasattr(inst, 'x'):
            print("should be printed only 1 time")
            inst.x = Test()
        return inst
```

In use:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
should be printed only 1 time
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> a is b
True
>>> a.x is b.x
True
```

Comment: it's a sort of workaround because if i've another class that extends MyClass, that must call the super().__new__() and then change x in constructor, i should write ugly code to implement an exclusive constructor for this second class with singleton. I think this pattern cannot be implemented in this way in python ( but i've read it in many books)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a singleton object would be to have another class method say get_instance which would ensure there is a singleton object for your class .. here is the snippet :

```
class Singleton(object):
    __instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if not cls.__instance:
            Singleton()
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        if Singleton.__instance is None:
            Singleton.__instance = self
            print("Object initialized")

singleton_1 = Singleton.get_instance()
singleton_2 = Singleton.get_instance()

if singleton_1 is singleton_2:
    print("Same")
else:
    print("Different")
```

The above snippet produces following output :

```
Object initialized
Same
```

Answer (score 0):

It's never too late i guess.. The answer is in fact in the question.

> i've noticed that the init is called, uselessly, everytime i call MyClass

So, just remove access to it (and probably from memory)...

```py
class Singleton:

    _instance = None
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        print('__new__()')

        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls) # Everything is normal python, no stress !

        elif cls.__init__.__name__ == '__init__':
            print("No need __init__ anymore, sorry, goodbye !")
            cls.__init__ = lambda *args: None # The __name__ of __init__ function is "<lambda>" now.

        print(cls._instance)

        return cls._instance # After this return, python call internally __init__(). Even if you set cls._instance to None, the __init__ function is not present anymore.

class App(Singleton):

    def __init__(self, number):
        print(f"Init only one time with number {number} !")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    App(24)
    App(53)
    App(63)
    App(63)
```

Output:

```
__new__()
<App object at 3ffe5e90>
Init only one time with number 24 !
__new__()
No need __init__ anymore, sorry, goodbye !
<App object at 3ffe5e90>
__new__()
<App object at 3ffe5e90>
__new__()
<App object at 3ffe5e90>
```